# Generic type to specify a class which extends another

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In this example I have a `Class` type which is defined as a class constructor so that I can define methods which accept class constructors as a parameter. I would like that `Class` also has a generic type that allows one to specify that the class should extend another class.

```
export type Class = { new(...args: any[]): any; };

class Document {
  id: string;
}

class Person extends Document {
  name: string;
}

export class Orm {

  registerDocument( model: Class ) {

  }

}

const orm = new Orm()
orm.registerDocument(Person)
```

I would like the `registerDocument` method to only accept class constructors which extends the `Document` class. My desired code would look like the example below, where the `Class` definition needs to be updated to support what I would like to do. The `Class` type should accept a type parameter, and also be able to be called without a type parameter (such as in the `foo` method).

```
// how should this type be defined?
export type Class<T> = { new(...args: any[]): any; };

class Document {
  id: string;
}

class Person extends Document {
  name: string;
}

class Foo {
  bar: string;
}

export class Orm {

  // accept class constructors that extend Document
  registerDocument( model: Class<Document> ) {

  }

  foo( acceptAnyClass: Class ) {

  }

}

const orm = new Orm()
orm.registerDocument(Person)
orm.foo(Foo)
```

Example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-arf3xr?file=index.ts)

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wX1Q9N) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Force the generic argument in `registerDocument()` to `extend Document` to make sure only `model`s of type `Document` or inherited class of `Document` can be passed. Also make sure to define the constructor signature to return `T`. Set a default generic value for  `Class<T>` in order to make the generic parameter optional.

```
class Document {
  id: string;
}

class Person extends Document {
  name: string;
}

class Foo {
  bar: string;
}

export class Orm {
  registerDocument<T extends Document>(model: Class<T>) {}
  foo<T>(acceptAnyClass: Class<T>) {}
}

type Class<T = any> = {new (...args: any[]): T};
const orm = new Orm();

orm.foo(Foo);
orm.registerDocument(Person);
orm.registerDocument(Foo);
//                   ~~~~
// Argument of type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to parameter of 
// type 'Class<Document>'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2wCuBbApgOwC7QN4FgAoaaASwBMAuaCLAJ1IwHNoBeaAIg4G4iBfIkVCQYABTR0I8DNDQAPLJnIwEydNjxESGMOmq0GzNpx79BhYVGgAxePE3FoAIzB199Ri3ZdehAYSJ5AAd4OhxLGAB5OhQHEjo0JlJaCVVUTCwAHgAVWQUlFUR07AA%20AAoUeHI0EGoAYXAoHJKASjx-EgAzO2aysGBgNCCsAEEMAE8GkXrGiGa23H9-IixxoLRoKabskuNcDDQAd2gygDpz1yYIajAJgG0AXRbqbL5fYGlaaFDY9gPj6IoMotXxEH6nbrwMq2eAgsExU4JJIpOhpdRYMriSTSOGEcFI5KKVFFdHQuy4gD0FJINNpdLpAD8mQyiFToCM6Exijh4J1oKt1tAAOQCtC8mx2IVkGAYeA4ESkJg6JwgDZYexBVy6NBE7580XCrZzNEZEpCoA)

Comment: That's close to what I was looking for. The one thing I would change is that type would be `Class<t=any>`. I have created an example here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xf5hfu?file=index.ts

Comment: Right, I overlooked that `T` for `Class` shouldn't be required.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the return type of the constructor definition in the `Class` type needs to be set to the generic, and the generic should have a default type parameter of <T = any>.

So

```
export type Class = { new(...args: any[]): any; };
```

Becomes

```
export type Class<T = any> = { new (...args: any[]): T };
```

Full example

```
export type Class<T = any> = { new (...args: any[]): T };

class Document {
  id: string;
}

class Person extends Document {
  name: string;
}

class Foo {
  bar: string;
}

export class Orm {
  registerDocument(model: Class<Document>) {}

  foo(foo: Class) {}
}

const orm = new Orm();

// acceptable
orm.registerDocument(Person);
orm.foo(Person);
orm.foo(Document);

// this one throws a type error
orm.registerDocument(Foo);
```

[Playground link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xf5hfu?file=index.ts)

Thanks to Behemoth's answer for pointing me in the right direction.